# How to create a unique IOT Thing on AWS automatically through a Flutter app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, iot, esp32, aws-iot

I am working on a project wherein a mobile app (Flutter app) should create a unique identity (IOT thing) of my IOT device machine (on AWS) as soon as the user logins onto the app and also it should establish a connection (and subsequent communications) with the isolated IOT device after its configuration (Somewhat similar to Google Home configuration process).

The process starts with user logging onto the app (using AWS Amplify/Congnito to automatically add the user account in the cloud). Subsequently, the app needs to configure the IOT device (ESP32) and send Wifi credentials of home network by connecting to ESP's WiFi AP. However, since both the app and IOT device are isolated from each other (except during the configuration process), I don't have much idea on how exactly will mobile app connect (creating a unique IOT thing automatically) and communicate with the isolated IOT device over AWS IOT cloud.

I have worked with some of the AWS services like AWS Lambda, DynamoDB, AWS IOT for quite a while, hence I am aware of the basics. One of the possible solutions for the above maybe **Fleet Provisioning by a Trusted User** feature provided by AWS IOT (I did read it's documentation, but still confused). We can also use ESP32's Bluetooth feature for the app to scan nearby devices with which it needs to connect with, but I am not sure how will the connection establish through AWS cloud.

Since I am a beginner to AWS cloud services, it'd be great if someone can provide a possible solution for the above in detail. Also if possible, please provide a solution which would work incase of a large-scale deployment of the above project.

Answer (score 0):

The parts you may be missing are missing are 1) MQTT messaging, which is the IoT message broker service provided by IoT Core, and 2) the need for an application program interface to handle creating and activating devices.

1. MQTT is a lightweight and widely adopted messaging protocol that is designed for constrained devices.

Your devices (things) will need to communicate back to AWS via MQTT messages, which are captured and processed by the IoT Rules service.

These rules typically trigger Lambda functions, which implement the process logic you need for your application.

See https://mqtt.org/ and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/what-is-aws-iot.html

2} you will want to implement a simple API to handle device activation. The AWS API Gateway service makes it easy to implement APIs. For example, you can implement an endpoint for `POST /device/` to create a device. That endpoint can trigger a Lambda handles device provisionsing.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of MQTT protocol over which communication will happen. But I am concerned about the connection part since everything should be automated without any manual intervention. How can I create a unique AWS IOT Thing (required for MQTT communication) for my IOT device automatically through app?. After this step, once the bidirectional connection is established, the further communication would happen through MQTT as you said

Comment: Ah got it. Yes You need an application API to create a new device first.

Comment: I expand on how to implement an API. Hope that helps

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. But now the question is how will my IOT device (ESP32) connect with AWS IOT endpoint(with the necessary certificates and key pairs without manual intervention) and finally connect with the just created IOT thing?. I don't want to hardcode the name of the IOT Thing in the code of my app and the code in ESP32. Somehow, the app should scan the devices (or maybe send some sort of information during configuration process) in its vicinity and connect the device to recently created AWS IOT Thing, that's what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Can the device download files? Does it have a unique identification id? I'd have it automatically activate by downloading its own configuration files from some https endpoint, that is tied to an ID you assign to the device eg serial number.